# Spark: scala - how to convert collection from RDD to another RDD

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

How can I convert collection returned after calling `take(5)` to another RDD so I can save first 5 records in output file?

if I use `saveAsTextfile` it is not letting me use `take` and `saveAsTextFile` together (that is why you are seeing that line commented below). It stores all records from RDD in sorted order so first 5 recs are top 5 countries but I want to store only first 5 records - is it possible to convert collections[take(5)] in RDD?

```
val Strips =  txtFileLines.map(_.split(","))
                         .map(line => (line(0) + "," + (line(7).toInt + line(8).toInt)))
                         .sortBy(x => x.split(",")(1).trim().toInt, ascending=false)
                         .take(5)
                       //.saveAsTextFile("output\\country\\byStripsBar")
```

**Solution:**
`sc.parallelize(Strips, 1).saveAsTextFile("output\\country\\byStripsBar")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val rowsArray: Array[Row] = rdd.take(5)
val slicedRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(rowsArray, 1)

slicedRdd.savesTextFile("specify path here")
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you absolutely need the `saveAsTextFile` formatting, I would just  print the `take(5)` output to a file using simple IO (like `File`).

Otherwise, here is the wordy `RDD` only solution:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(5 to 1 by -1 map{x => (x, x*x)})
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[71] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> rdd.collect
res1: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((5,25), (4,16), (3,9), (2,4), (1,1))

scala> val top2 = rdd.sortBy(_._1).zipWithIndex.collect{case x if (x._2 < 2) => x._1}
top2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[79] at collect at <console>:29

scala> top2.collect
res2: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,1), (2,4))
```